# Task execution for every one hour, even when app is closed in expo

Tags: react-native, expo, scheduler

I need to fetch data from api and update in SQLite database every hour (Like backup and view when offline).

I have tried [TaskManager](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v36.0.0/sdk/task-manager/) with [BackgroundFetch](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v36.0.0/sdk/background-fetch/) to run task at background,
but it runs only when the app is minimised and not when the app is terminated.

**Existing code**

```
import * as BackgroundFetch from "expo-background-fetch";
import * as TaskManager from "expo-task-manager";

export async function registerTask() {

TaskManager.defineTask(TASKNAME,taskFunction);

const status = await BackgroundFetch.getStatusAsync();

switch (status) {
  case BackgroundFetch.Status.Restricted:
  case BackgroundFetch.Status.Denied:
    console.log("Background execution is disabled");
    return;

  default: {
    console.debug("Background execution allowed");

    let tasks = await TaskManager.getRegisteredTasksAsync();
    if (tasks.find((f) => f.taskName === TASKNAME) == null) {
      console.log("Registering task");
      await BackgroundFetch.registerTaskAsync(TASKNAME,{
        minimumInterval: INTERVAL,
        startOnBoot : true,
        stopOnTerminate : false
      });

      tasks = await TaskManager.getRegisteredTasksAsync();
      console.debug("Registered tasks", tasks);
    } else {
      console.log(`Task ${TASKNAME} already registered, skipping`);
    }

    // console.log("Setting interval to", INTERVAL);
    // await BackgroundFetch.setMinimumIntervalAsync(INTERVAL);
  }
}
}
```

**In App.js**

```
registerTask();
```

I really need something to work both on foreground and background and as well as when the app is closed.

Thanks in advance.

**Note:**
Need solution compatible to [Expo](https://docs.expo.io/)